# Execute test case from Excel

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have one excel sheet where all the classes which need to be executed are written. Now I need to execute those test cases only. Can anyone tell me how can this be possible. Using Selenium(java):

[image: image description]

Comment: Use Apache POI to read the excel from java... Why dont you setup the same using junit or testng. Much simpler.

Comment: I know about testNg, but the requirement is to take test cases from excel, so that they can change the order of execution anytime. If we use testNg, we have to do changes in code if they want to change the order of execution, which is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You are making life difficult for yourself.

A simpler / better approach would be to export the spreadsheet as a CSV, and then use a (simple) CSV reader class.